# Tkinter GUI not opening when compiled

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop, keyboardinterrupt

My python program I created doesn't seem to be opening when I click compile. The reason I am confused is because I have a .mainloop() attached to the class. Through my own testing I have deduced that it has something to do with the while loop in my code. Additionally, not sure if this helps, but when I abort the program the following appears in the console:

```
File "C:\Users\zach\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2585, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)

   KeyboardInterrupt
```

here is my completed code for:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Lab 8")
        self.grid()
        canvas_width = 800
        canvas_height = 400
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = canvas_width, height =
                             canvas_height, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.grid()

        ball_diameter = 20
        top_x = 2
        top_y = 2
        self.canvas.create_oval(top_x, top_y, top_x + ball_diameter,
                                top_y + ball_diameter, fill = "black", tags = "ball")

        horizontal_direction = "east"
        vertical_direction = "south"
        dx = 2
        dy = 2

        while True:
            if horizontal_direction == "east":
                self.canvas.move("ball", dx, 0) # move ball horizontally dx pixels to the right/east
                top_x += dx # dx is 2 because the ball moves 2 pixels horizontally every 15 milliseconds
                if top_x >= canvas_width - ball_diameter: # ball has hit east wall
                    horizontal_direction = "west" # change direction
            else: # i.e., horizontal_direction is "west"
                self.canvas.move("ball", -dx, 0) # move ball horizontally dx pixels to the left/west
                top_x -= dx
                if top_x <= 0: # ball has hit west wall
                    horizontal_direction = "east" # change direction
            if vertical_direction == "south":
                self.canvas.move("ball", 0, dy)
                top_y += dy
                if top_y >= canvas_height - ball_diameter:
                    vertical_direction = "north"
            else:
                self.canvas.move("ball", 0, -dy)
                top_y -= dy
                if top_y <= 0 :
                    vertical_direction = "south"


def main():
    GUI().mainloop()

main()
```

I figured it out it was because I forgot to add the update and after methods to wait for the ball and update its position.

Comment: hi @Zachary I was wondering if the below answer is/was useful to you? If its not please let me know, so I can update it. If it was useful consider making it the accepted answer by clicking on the green tick.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you run an infinite loop in your `__init__` function. It will never reach your main loop to run the GUI. You need to let `__init__` end and to call your update code, not in a tight loop but at a set time interval.

Break out the code to move the shape into a separate function, minus the infinite loop and call that function at intervals using the `after` method of tk widgets.

```
from tkinter import * 

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Lab 8")
        self.grid()
        self.canvas_width = 800
        self.canvas_height = 400
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, 
                             width=self.canvas_width, 
                             height=self.canvas_height, 
                             bg="white")
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.ball_diameter = 20
        self.top_x = 2
        self.top_y = 2
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.top_x, 
                                self.top_y, 
                                self.top_x + self.ball_diameter,
                                self.top_y + self.ball_diameter, 
                                fill = "black", tags = "ball")

        self.horizontal_direction = "east"
        self.vertical_direction = "south"
        self.dx = 2
        self.dy = 2

        self.after(10, self.move)


    def move(self):

        if self.horizontal_direction == "east":
            self.canvas.move("ball", self.dx, 0) # move ball horizontally dx pixels to the right/east
            self.top_x += self.dx # dx is 2 because the ball moves 2 pixels horizontally every 15 milliseconds
            if self.top_x >= self.canvas_width - self.ball_diameter: # ball has hit east wall
                self.horizontal_direction = "west" # change direction
        else: # i.e., horizontal_direction is "west"
            self.canvas.move("ball", -self.dx, 0) # move ball horizontally dx pixels to the left/west
            self.top_x -= self.dx 
            if self.top_x <= 0: # ball has hit west wall
                self.horizontal_direction = "east" # change direction

        if self.vertical_direction == "south":
            self.canvas.move("ball", 0, self.dy)
            self.top_y += self.dy
            if self.top_y >= self.canvas_height - self.ball_diameter:
                self.vertical_direction = "north"
        else:
            self.canvas.move("ball", 0, -self.dy)
            self.top_y -= self.dy
            if self.top_y <= 0 :
                self.vertical_direction = "south"

        self.after(10, self.move)


def main():
    GUI().mainloop()

main()
```

Note that the number of `self` variables has exploded and become pretty unmanageable IMHO, which might indicate you need to break out some of those values into other classes.

But fundamentally this runs. It ain't pretty, but you can work on that next.